# Relationship between tables with two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, uml

I have a `users(id)` table and a `friends(user_id1, user_id2)` where `user_id1` and `user_id2` are both foreign keys to the `users` table.

What relationship is this ?

I think is One to Many, but since I have the user id two times it's a bit confusing. 
(I have to make a diagram and don't know what relationship to use).

Comment: I think One to Many relation is correct. Because a user can have many friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This UML class diagram describes the situation ([yuml.me script (click to edit)](http://yuml.me/diagram/plain/class/edit/[%3C%3CTable%3E%3E;users%7Bbg:lightskyblue%7D]%202%20%3C-%20*%20[%3C%3CTable%3E%3E;friends%7Bbg:gold%7D]))

[image]

In UML terms the line's name is [navigable association](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability) with known [multiplicity](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html).

In order to draw a diagram you don't need to give the relationship another "name"

Answer (score 1):

There are two "one-to-many" relationships...

Users.id --> 1 to many --> friends.userid1

Users.id --> 1 to many --> friends.userid2

Answer (score 1):

I would model it like this:

[image]

This is actually the logical data model that is implemented with the database model you mentioned.

I don't think it's a good idea to mix database terminology (Table) with functional/logical notions (association wit multiplicity 2)

Comment: You are right that it is important not to mix up different things. However, it's completely meaning ful to make two kinds of class diagrams here: first, a platform-independent logical design model, and a platform-specific data model derived from it. Your model is a logical design model, while the model proposed by xmojmr is such a data model (it could be called "RDB model" or "SQL data model"), although it may be preferable to model two many-to-one associations between `friends`and ùsers`instead of his many-to-two association.